# can we display Purchase Order as a payment method for non-logged in customers also?

Tags: magento-1.9

Purchase order payment method available for all customer groups except Non-Logged-in customers on the checkout page.
can we display Purchase Order as a payment method for non-logged in customers also?

Answer (score 2):

This is enabled in Magento by default.

Is it possible that you have a module installed that would disable that? 
Probably it'd look similar to what's in answer here:
[How to disable purchase order for guest checkout?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140547/how-to-disable-purchase-order-for-guest-checkout/142217)